# send mms with multiple files to multiple contacts

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sms

I want to send 2 vcard files to 2 contacts with intent:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, savedFile);
String numbers = vCardElements.get(0).getPhone_1() + ";" + vCardElements.get(1).getPhone_1();
sendIntent.putExtra("address", "1231213;13232132");
sendIntent.setType("text/x-vcard");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

I have tried with this but it's asking me to select the recipients but I want to pass that in the intent